# JsTree Checkbox checked unchecked with based on condition jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, jstree

I am trying to JsTree Checkbox checked unchecked based on condition.
i have to checked and unchecked based dropdown change event.
string has value 0 and 1.
0 means unchecked and 1 means checked.
[This is my menu design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB9hO.png)

Here is my controller code.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSingleUser(int id)
    {
        MachineShopDBEntities DB = new MachineShopDBEntities();
        var SPresult = DB.GetSingleUser(id).FirstOrDefault();
        return Json(SPresult);
    }
```

Here is my Script.

```
 $("#UserSelect").change(function () {
        $.post("/MenuMaster/GetSingleUser?id=" + $(this).val(),
                function (data, status) {

                    var databaseString = data.MenuEnable;
                    var count = $('.menux ul li').length;
                    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                            if (databaseString[i] == '0') {

                                $('.menux .jstree-anchor').removeClass('jstree-clicked');
                            }
                            else {

                                $('.menux .jstree-anchor').addClass('jstree-clicked');
                            }
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: based on databaseString[i] i have to checked and unchecked checkbox  in jstree. databasestring has value 0 and 1.

Comment: so you question is "how do i  checked and unchecked checkbox based on databaseString[i] ?"

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `eq` function to select the element based on index i

```
 $("#UserSelect").change(function () {
        $.post("/MenuMaster/GetSingleUser?id=" + $(this).val(),
                function (data, status) {

                    var databaseString = data.MenuEnable;
                    var count = $('.menux ul li').length;
                    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                            if (databaseString[i] == '0') {

                                $('.menux .jstree-anchor').eq(i).removeClass('jstree-clicked');
                            }
                            else {

                                $('.menux .jstree-anchor').eq(i).addClass('jstree-clicked');
                            }
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: @Azazkhan glad to have helped